# CPythonをAndroidアプリに埋め込むことは可能か

Tags: python, android

CPythonインタプリタ(JythonやKivyなどではなくCで書かれたPythonの処理系(一般的なPython))をAndroidアプリに埋め込んでPythonのコードをアプリ上で実行することは可能ですか?
Kivyなどの他の処理系を使うこともできますが、それをせず、CPythonを使うならどうすればいいのでしょうか?

CPythonインタプリタとその依存関係(OpenSSL, xzなど)をAndroid NDK toolchainを使ってビルドしてAndroidアプリ内に埋め込みたいです。そしてCPythonのC bindingなどをJNIから呼び出したいです。このようなことは可能でしょうか?

そもそもCPythonをAndroid NDK toolchain を使ってビルドできるのでしょうか?
(Raspberry Piでは動くのでAArch64/Linuxではビルドできますが、Androidではどうなのでしょうか?)

Comment: kivy/python-for-android で具体的にお困りの箇所はありますか？　python-for-android も処理には CPython + Cython を[使っており](https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart/#installing-dependencies)、適切に [recipe](https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes/) を作ってあげれば色々とできるはずだと思っています（いま試せる環境が無いので試せていませんが……）。